# Moments of the Kolmogorov distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, st.statistics

Up to what order do the moments of the [Kolmogorov distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov_distribution) exist? References would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use the cumulative distribution function?


Comment: @Davide Thanks. I know that I could try by integrating the density or by using $E[X^n]=\int n x^{n-1}P(X>x)$. However, since both approaches involve the integration of an alternating series, I was looking for a credible reference that justifies the steps. My google-foo has not lead me to a helpful reference yet.


Comment: In addition, by wildly interchanging the series and the integration process, I came up to the conclusion that all the moments exist. But I would like to confirm this.


Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kolmogorov distribution is defined by the distribution of the random variable $K:=\sup_{0\leqslant t\leqslant 1}|B(t)|$, where $B(t)$ is the Brownian Bridge.

The problem of existence of moments for $K$ is actually the same as the study of moments of $K':=\sup_{0\leqslant t\leqslant 1}|W(t)|$, where $W(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion. An application of [Doob's (sub)martingale inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality) gives that for all $C>0$,
$$P(K'\geqslant C)\leqslant \exp\left(-\frac{C^2}2\right).$$

Using the fact that for a non-negative random variable $X$ and $p>1$, we have $$E(X^p)=\int_0^{+\infty}pt^{p-1}P(X\geqslant t)dt,$$
we conclude that Kolmogorov distribution admits moments of any order.

Comment: Many thanks. Very nice answer. Before accepting, can we say something about the existence of moments for $p<0$ using the same argument?

Comment: We have for $p<0$ that $K^p\leqslant |B(1)|^p$ hence there are moments of order $p$ for $0-1<p<0$.